# Devexpress - Null reference exception after inserting previously deleted series

Tags: c#, devexpress, charts

I have a strange problem with XtraChart control. I put XtraChart control on form , and created one data series. After form initialization I create a variable which holds the reference for this series

```
public XtraChartSeriesPoint()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           KeySeries = (Series)chartControl1.Series["key"];
       }
```

At this point everything is OK. However problem occurs if I start manipulate the dataseries. If I delete series KeySeries from diagram diagram and then I add this series  again I get nullReferenceException.​

```
chartControl1.Series.Remove(KeySeries); // everything OK - points are removed from diagram 

chartControl1.Series.Add(KeySeries); // here I get nullReferenceException
```

Here is a link to sample project. ​
http://www.4shared.com/file/6CycXjJr/DevexpressTraining.html 
To get an error just click on remove button and then on add​

Comment: KeySeries = (Series)chartControl1.Series["key"]
Reference the internal series of chart so could you see in debugger which value is in KeyValues after the Series.Remove(KeyValues) line? Is it NULL?

Comment: @sllev The problem is that KeySeries is not null :( The exception is probably raised by some internal Devexpress function

Comment: commando could you paste the Stack Trace from the NullReferenceException so we can get some understanding where it is failing?

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the Series, its Dispose method is called.  So, it becomes invalid and cannot be used any more.  If you want to hide a Series, work its Visible property.

Comment: Actually I voted this up before I had looked into it :( It doesn't actually call the ChartElement.Dispose on Remove.

Comment: Actually, my answer was correct.  Check the value of the PVSeries.IsDisposed property after the Remove method is called...

Answer (score 0):

Commando, What are you doing when you have removed the series?

I have create a fresh project, placed a Chart Control on the form, then just click Finish on the Wizard to obtain basic chart with a single series. I then on Form Load have

```
series = ChartControl1.Series(0)
ChartControl1.Series.Remove(series)
ChartControl1.Series.Add(series)
```

This doesn't cause any exception. So I assume it has something to do with your processing of the series, such as a Datasource.

If you could place the Stack Trace of the exception in your question it might allow us to understand it better.

So look into what you are doing to the series or chart while it is detached as I believe this is where your problem may lay.